# Antd table grouping data from dynamic data

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to build an Antd table, where I have two main columns `District, Exam Details`. Inside `Exam Details` column I want to have three columns

- Gender Details
- Total number of candidates
- Total number of candidates passed

as shown below

[image: required way of table design]

I tried this code: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/grouped-data-u93u4)

Comment: is it okay if i tweak the data array a bit?

Comment: Trying for a solution, if one solution is there then it will be great. Its fine for now for tweaking the array to get a output

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have changed the columns to have children. It's pretty close to what you like to achieve.

```
const columns = [
    {
      title: "District",
      dataIndex: "state_name",
      key: "state_name",
      render: (value, row, index) => {
        const obj = {
          children: value,
          props: {}
        };
        console.log(obj.children, index);
        if (index % 3 === 0) {
          obj.props.rowSpan = 3;
        }
        // These two are merged into above cell
        if (index % 3 === 1) {
          obj.props.rowSpan = 0;
        }
        if (index % 3 === 2) {
          obj.props.rowSpan = 0;
        }
        return obj;
      }
    },
    {
      title: "Exam Details",
      children: [
        {
          title: "Gender Details",
          dataIndex: "gender",
          key: 1
        },
        {
          title: "Total number of candidates",
          dataIndex: "total",
          key: 2
        },
        {
          title: "Total Number of candidates passed",
          dataIndex: "passed_total",
          key: 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  const data = [
    {
      state_name: "Karnataka",
      gender: "Boys",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    },
    {
      state_name: "Karnataka",
      gender: "Girls",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    },
    {
      state_name: "Karnataka",
      gender: "Transgender",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    },
    {
      state_name: "Kerala",
      gender: "Boys",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    },
    {
      state_name: "Kerala",
      gender: "Girls",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    },
    {
      state_name: "Kerala",
      gender: "Transgender",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    },
    {
      state_name: "Tamilnadu",
      gender: "Boys",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    },
    {
      state_name: "Tamilnadu",
      gender: "Girls",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    },
    {
      state_name: "Tamilnadu",
      gender: "Transgender",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    },
    {
      state_name: "Goa",
      gender: "Boys",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    },
    {
      state_name: "Goa",
      gender: "Girls",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    },
    {
      state_name: "Goa",
      gender: "Transgender",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    },
    {
      state_name: "Andhra Pradesh",
      gender: "Boys",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    },
    {
      state_name: "Andhra Pradesh",
      gender: "Girls",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    },
    {
      state_name: "Andhra Pradesh",
      gender: "Transgender",
      total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10),
      passed_total: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
    }
  ];
```

[Sandbox url](https://codesandbox.io/s/grouped-data-muptr)

@Update

Figured out the issue, basically having a variable outside, when the sameKey repeats not setting the count making rowSpan as 0 so it will be hidden.

Logic

```
let sameKey;
  const columns = [
    {
      title: "District",
      dataIndex: "state_name",
      key: "state_name",
      render: (value, row, index) => {
        const obj = {
          children: value,
          props: {}
        };
        if (!(sameKey !== value)) {
          obj.props.rowSpan = 0;
          return obj;
        }
        const count = data.filter(item => item.state_name === value).length;
        sameKey = value;
        obj.props.rowSpan = count;
        return obj;
      }
    },
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/grouped-data-muptr) with dyanmic number of gender rows

Comment: but one doubt, if i remove girls, boys or transgender data in any of the state it will show in wrong order. because we are hardcoding the logic isn't

Comment: Yes, it's importantant to have three groups of gender. But we can try to make it dynamic as well.

Comment: thats what i wanted because some state wont have three gender as you can see in the screen shot andhrapradesh having one and goa having two

Comment: i think we need to do a count of the item and use that count   let count = data.filter(d => d.state_name === value).length; isn't ?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: any update on it, i tried but its not getting in a proper way

Comment: i have added the update with the count value issue, solved it thanks for the info and help :)

Comment: bro.. can you help me too? i've raise my question -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67672792/how-to-merge-rowspan-in-antd)