# How to Merge RowSpan in Antd

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, antd

. I got the task to change the array of objects according to the desired table but I had problems adjusting it. I want the data table as below

[image]
*note: data in image in not valid.

here's my data for my row:

```
[
    {
        "key": 0,
        "source": "offline",
        "price": 7000,
        "avgSales": 18336
    },
    {
        "key": 1,
        "source": "Online",
        "price": 8000,
        "avgSales": 13874
    },
    {
        "key": 2,
        "source": "Online",
        "price": 29000,
        "avgSales": 17752
    },
    {
        "key": 3,
        "source": "Online",
        "price": 9000,
        "avgSales": 17070
    },
    {
        "key": 4,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 11000,
        "avgSales": 5270
    },
    {
        "key": 5,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 28000,
        "avgSales": 3019
    },
    {
        "key": 6,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 17500,
        "avgSales": 12518
    },
    {
        "key": 7,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 85000,
        "avgSales": 12301
    },
    {
        "key": 8,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 15000,
        "avgSales": 18336
    },
    {
        "key": 9,
        "source": "Online",
        "price": 16000,
        "avgSales": 13874
    },
    {
        "key": 10,
        "source": "Online",
        "price": 25000,
        "avgSales": 17752
    },
    {
        "key": 11,
        "source": "Online",
        "price": 15000,
        "avgSales": 17070
    },
    {
        "key": 12,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 11000,
        "avgSales": 3019
    },
    {
        "key": 13,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 8000,
        "avgSales": 12518
    },
    {
        "key": 14,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 28000,
        "avgSales": 12301
    },
    {
        "key": 15,
        "source": "Online",
        "price": 11000,
        "avgSales": 13874
    },
    {
        "key": 16,
        "source": "Online",
        "price": 9000,
        "avgSales": 17752
    },
    {
        "key": 17,
        "source": "Online",
        "price": 8000,
        "avgSales": 17070
    },
    {
        "key": 18,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 29000,
        "avgSales": 5270
    },
    {
        "key": 19,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 85000,
        "avgSales": 12518
    },
    {
        "key": 20,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 15000,
        "avgSales": 12301
    },
    {
        "key": 21,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 29000,
        "avgSales": 18336
    },
    {
        "key": 22,
        "source": "Online",
        "price": 17500,
        "avgSales": 13874
    },
    {
        "key": 23,
        "source": "Online",
        "price": 85000,
        "avgSales": 17752
    },
    {
        "key": 24,
        "source": "Online",
        "price": 11000,
        "avgSales": 17070
    },
    {
        "key": 25,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 15000,
        "avgSales": 5270
    },
    {
        "key": 26,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 85000,
        "avgSales": 3019
    },
    {
        "key": 27,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 11000,
        "avgSales": 12518
    },
    {
        "key": 28,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 29000,
        "avgSales": 12301
    },
    {
        "key": 29,
        "source": "Online",
        "price": 22000,
        "avgSales": 13874
    },
    {
        "key": 30,
        "source": "Online",
        "price": 15000,
        "avgSales": 17752
    },
    {
        "key": 31,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 9500,
        "avgSales": 5270
    },
    {
        "key": 32,
        "source": "Offline",
        "price": 9500,
        "avgSales": 3019
    }
]
```

column:

```
const columns = [
                {
                    title    : 'Source',
                    dataIndex: 'source',
                    key      : 'source',
                },
                {
                    title    : 'Price',
                    dataIndex: 'price',
                    key      : 'price',
                },
                {
                    title    : 'Average of Sales',
                    dataIndex: 'avgSales',
                    key      : 'avgSales',
                },
            ];
```

I still try but still fail. already looking for a related way in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559877/antd-table-grouping-data-from-dynamic-data) still failed. i really got stuck.

I hope you guys can help me. thank you

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: already did the same as your answer but replace the key 'state_name' with 'source' according to mine .. but instead my column [disappears](https://ibb.co/fqP3vLD)

Comment: In this case you should try nested table https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-nested-table. this will give you the nearest possible results for the expected funtionality.

Comment: but why use nested tables? my job is to make the data according to the table above. not nested. is it not possible to make the table the way I want?

Comment: antd does not provide an option to merge the cells vertically and also you need the fuctionality to collapese the rows and need show the aggregated value - the way Excel works.  to achieve this i think it's a good start to use nested tables.

Comment: ohh ok.. so this is imposible to implement? so.. maybe i'll do it in traditional table with antd styles.. thanks for help

Comment: @HeruWijayanto I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67792863/10220474) is your answer

Comment: thank you for the answer @simaghoreyshi but I have done it using my traditional way, and this is last my project 6 months ago, perhaps this answer will useful in my next project.